# WSO2 ESB doesn't have security options for services

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to deploy this example:

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2012/08/securing-sts-security-token-service-kerberos/

I'm doing in the version of the ESB 4.9.0. The problem I'm facing is that I can't find the security options for the echo proxy service.

Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling security for services via the UI was removed from ESB 4.9.0. This is removed from other service hosting supported middleware of WSO2 such as Data Services server and Application Server. Now the recommended way of securing the services is via the WSO2 Developer Studio. See the following webinar.
http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2015/12/how-to-secure-your-enterprise-services-with-wso2-esb-4.9/

And also the following documentation.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service

Comment: Thanks for your time and your answer, I was lost!!